# chaining a table of object with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have two tables

```
Players table (object)
-------------
PlayerID
Name
Birthday
List<Matches> Matches
```

and

```
Matches table
--------------
MatchID
PlayerID
TeamID
```

How can i get a list of players and every row of the Player object contains a list of Matches that he has played ?

Sincerly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try just a normal join in LiNQ:

```
from p in Players
join m in Matches on p.PlayerID equals m.PlayerID
select new { p, m }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up `Matches.PlayerID` as a foreign key to `Players`, then LINQ should create a `playerInstance.Matches` List.

(Assuming you're building a database then running SQLMetal, doing it in Entity Framework may be different, although the relationship still needs to be modelled)